# Java: one field of three possible types?

Tags: java

I have a box class. The box contains a filter.

```
public class Box {
    private Filter filter;

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public void add filter() {
        filter = new Filter();
    }
}
```

There can only be one filter per box, but there are 3 different types of filters. Each type of filter uses different parameters to calculate filter efficiency and such. Up to this point, I have used one filter class that implements all functionality for every filter type:

```
public class Filter {
    // filter fields/functions shared by each filter
    ...

   // filter fields/functions unique to filter type 1
   ...

   // filter fields/functions unique to filter type 2
   ...

   // filter fields/functions unique to filter type 3
   ...
}
```

This works, but I don't like carrying unneeded/not initialized  fields once I construct the filter. For instance, if the filter object is of type 1, it still stores the parameters unique to type 2 and type 3, because there is only 1 filter class. To prevent this, I have decided to use inheritance:

```
public class Filter {
    // filter fields/functions shared by each filter
    ...
}

public class Filter1 extends Filter {
    // filter fields/functions unique to filter type 1
    ...
}

public class Filter2 extends Filter {
    // filter fields/functions unique to filter type 2
    ...
}

public class Filter3 extends Filter {
    // filter fields/functions unique to filter type 3
    ...
}
```

This solves the above problem. However, now the box class will need to differentiate between each filter. I do not want to do the below, because now the box will be storing null filters, as there can only be one filter per box.

```
public class box {
    private Filter1 filter1;
    private Filter2 filter2;
    private Filter3 filter3;

    public Filter1 getFilter() {
        return filter1;
    }

    public Filter2 getFilter() {
        return filter2;
    }

    public Filter3 getFilter() {
        return filter3;
    }

    public void add filter1() {
        filter = new Filter1();
    }

    public void add filter2() {
        filter = new Filter2();
    }

    public void add filter3() {
        filter = new Filter3();
    }
}
```

I want something like the following:

```
public class Box {
    private filter; // either of type Filter1, Filter2, or Filter3

    public getFilter() { //somehow specify correct return type
        return filter;
    }

    public void add filter1() {
        filter = new Filter1();
    }

    public void add filter2() {
        filter = new Filter2();
    }

    public void add filter3() {
        filter = new Filter3();
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Summary: In short, I need one box filter that can be of multiple types. I need to be able to access the unique fields/methods of this filter depending on its type. I do not want to store multiple null filters in the box, and I do not want one big filter class that lumps the functionality of every filter type together.

Comment: When you say 'differentiate'; is there any reason the `Filter` class itself can't handle that differentiation?  Have some `getName()` (or whatever other differentiation you require) on it; and then you can just use `filter.getDifferentiator()`.

Comment: If I understand your problem, make some super class (or interface) Filter then have your three unique filters extend (or implement) the class. From there you can have all methods using the filters just use the generic filter class

Comment: Just use the super class `Filter` for your field `filter`.

Comment: Making `Filter` an `interface` is more appropriate, then you can have a `Filter` member in `Box`, passing the correct/desired implementation when you instantiate it. Although you can have `filter` to be of type `Filter` as it is right now.

Comment: @x80486 Will this allow me to access the fields unique to the filter implementation? For example, elsewhere in the code, if I need to access the field filter.flowRate (a field in one of the implementing classes), how can I do that if the filter is of type IFilter?

Comment: Like any other `interface`, you can only access what's defined there; if you need access to "specialized" methods, only found in specific implementations, you would need to cast `filter` to the correct type.

Comment: If you need to access specific fields of filters elsewhere in the code, then this is a code smell - meaning that something is wrong with your design. Think of redesigning it. You shouldn't expose the implementation details of filters outside the `Filter` classes.

Comment: By the way, I wonder how do you plan to use that? Try to do it; you would need to know beforehand that you are going to use something specific for a particular class, then that could be your entry-point to cast, for instance `filter`, to a more specialized type.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to find a design in which `Box` does not need to care what kind of `Filter` its filter is. If `Box` needs to know, you should consider a redesign. Sometimes you need this kind of information, but 99% of the time you do not.

For example, if only `Filter1` has a `flowRate` and only `Filter2` has a `density`, and you are doing something like the following...

```
class Box
{
    void doStuff()
    {
        if(filter.isFilter1) doFlowStuff(filter.flowRate);
        if(filter.isFilter2) doDensityStuff(filter.density);
    }
}
```

Then you should try to move that logic out of `Box` and into `Filter1` and `Filter2`

```
class Box
{
    void doStuff()
    {
        a();
        filter.doFilterStuff();
        b();
    }
}

interface Filter
{
    void doFilterStuff();
}

class Filter1 implements Filter
{
    void doFilterStuff()
    {
        doFlowStuff(flowRate);
    }
}

class Filter2 implements Filter
{
    void doFilterStuff()
    {
        doDensityStuff(density);
    }
}
```

Note that this will not satisfy your desire to have `Box.getFilter` return type be the sub-type you desire. `getFilter` can return a `Filter1` or a `Filter2`, but the code that calls `getFilter` will see a `Filter`, not a `Filter1`.

Or, if that just does not make sense in your situation because it really is the `Box` that should be doing the stuff, then that means you probably don't have just 1 type of box and you're trying to cram multiple different `Box` logics into 1 `Box` when you really should have different types...

```
interface Box
{
    void doBoxStuff();
}

class Box1 implements Box
{
    Filter1 filter;

    void doBoxStuff()
    {
        filter.doFlowStuff();
    }
}

class Box2 implements Box
{
    Filter2 filter;

    void doBoxStuff()
    {
        filter.doDensityStuff();
    }
}
```

That is, if you absolutely must have the logic be in box and if the filters must have different attributes and methods. If you do it this way, with multiple box types, you can still have `Filter1` and `Filter2` inherit from `Filter` if their functionality overlaps enough that it makes sense, but `Box1` and `Box2` will not keep track of a generic `Filter` but instead will keep track only of the specific type of filter they are able to work with. After all, you don't want a `Box2` trying to operate on a `Filter1`.

This also allows you to have your box return the correct filter type from `getFilter`. `Box1` can have `Filter1 getFilter`, and `Box2` can have a `Filter2 getFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that could fit your case better. Instead of casting the `Filter` to specific filter types, you can use generics. In this case, when you construct a `Box` object, you tell it what kind of a filter it contains. As far as I understood, you need to be able to retrieve a `Filter` from a `Box` by calling `getFilter()` method.

Here's a very simple scenario:

```
public interface Filter {
}
```

```
public class FilterOne implements Filter {
    public String method1() {
        return "This is filter one";
    }
}
```

```
public class FilterTwo implements Filter {
    public int method2() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

```
public class Box<T extends Filter> {
    T filter;

    public Box(T filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    public T getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Then you would construct `Box` objects this way:

```
public class BoxTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<FilterOne> boxOne = new Box<>(new FilterOne());
        Box<FilterTwo> boxTwo = new Box<>(new FilterTwo());
        System.out.println(boxOne.getFilter().method1());
        System.out.println(boxTwo.getFilter().method2());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do using a superclass and subclasses. I like the ability to define code that is used by all filter types in the superclass and only the specialized code in the subclasses (vs interface implementation).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // tell your box which kind of filter you want it to create
    Box myBox = new Box(Filter.TYPE_1);

    // perform filter, the filter object will know what to do
    myBox.getFilter().doSomeFiltering();

    // if you need interact with your filter subclass variables
    Filter myFilter = myBox.getFilter();
    int filterType = myFilter.getFilterType();
    switch(filterType) {
        case Filter.TYPE_1:
            boolean foo = ((Filter1)myFilter).getFooVal();
            break;
        case Filter.TYPE_2:
            double bar = ((Filter2)myFilter).getBarVal();
            break;
        case Filter.TYPE_3:
            long uniq = ((Filter3)myFilter).getUniqueParam();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

public class Box {
    private Filter filter;
    private int filterType;

    public Box(int type) {
        this.filterType = type;
        setFilter();
    }

    public void setFilter() {
        switch(filterType) {
            case Filter.TYPE_1:
                filter = new Filter1();
                break;
            case Filter.TYPE_2:
                filter = new Filter2();
                break;
            case Filter.TYPE_3:
                filter = new Filter3();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
}

public class Filter { 
    public static final int TYPE_1 = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_2 = 2;
    public static final int TYPE_3 = 3;

    public int type = -1;

    public void doSomeFiltering(){
        // this will be overridden in subclasses
    }

    public int getFilterType() {
        return type;
    }
}

public class Filter1 extends Filter {
    private boolean fooVal = true;

    public Filter1() {
        super.type = TYPE_1;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomeFiltering() {
        // actual code, can be different for each subclass and called by superclass
    }

    public boolean getFooVal() {
        return fooVal;
    }
}

public class Filter2 extends Filter {
    private double barVal = 7;

    public Filter2() {
        super.type = TYPE_2;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomeFiltering() {
        // actual code, can be different for each subclass and called by superclass
    }

    public double getBarVal() {
        return barVal;
    }
}

public class Filter3 extends Filter {
    private long uniqueParam = 42;

    public Filter3() {
        super.type = TYPE_3;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomeFiltering() {
        // actual code, can be different for each subclass and called by superclass
    }

    public long getUniqueParam() {
        return uniqueParam;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Absolutely, what you want is the recommended code practice (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Basically, you should code to interfaces or superclasses. In this case, I would define a super-class `Filter` with state and behaviour that is common to all filters. `Filter1`, `Filter2`, `Filter3` would extend from `Filter`, as I clearly see a is-a relationship b/w the super-class and the sub-classes. Here's the code:

```
public class Box {
    private Filter filter; //super-class

    public getFilter() { //somehow specify correct return type
        return this.filter;
    }

    public void add filter1() {
        filter = new Filter1();
    }

    public void add filter2() {
        filter = new Filter2();
    }

    public void add filter3() {
        filter = new Filter3();
    }
}
```

We can also define `Filter` as an interface (it can even be a marker interface with no methods at all). Then, `FilterX` can implement that interface. The exact above code with work in this case as well.

One point to note is that you'll only be able to use methods that are defined in the super-class/interface. This is because the reference variable is of the type `Filter`.

Comment: I don't know who has down-voted it, so I can't know the exact reason. However, I'm sure one of the reasons is because your answer is full of compile-time errors. Even if you fix the compile-time errors, it still has design issues, there is a strong coupling between `Box` and all implementations of `Filter`. If you add a new filter, you will have to modify the `Box` class, too. And, that is a bad practice.

Comment: Of course it'll full of compile-time errors if you paste it as it. You'll have to write the superclass and extend from it. Further, the OP asked a very specific question about the Liskov principle and I think the answer answers that. OP did not ask about loose coupling or any other design pattern.